# Error permission on MAC OSX to JAVE

Tags: java, macos, permissions, processing

I want to create a software which convert a Video in Audio. 
I use PROCESSING (JAVA) and JAVE for this. 
My problem is "`it.sauronsoftware.jave.InputFormatException`", this code work on `Windows` but not in `OSX`.

I think it's probably a problem of permission.

```
String pathVideo="/Users/nouv/Desktop/video1";
String pathAudioTmp="/Users/nouv/Desktop/son";

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);

 try {
    File source = new File(pathVideo);
    File target = new File(pathAudioOutput);
    AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
    audio.setCodec("libmp3lame");
    audio.setBitRate(new Integer(128000));
    audio.setChannels(new Integer(2));
    audio.setSamplingRate(new Integer(44100));
    EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
    attrs.setFormat("mp3");
    attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);
    Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
    encoder.encode(source, target, attrs); 

  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
    println(e);
  }
```

Comment: You most likely need native libraries for this platform too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you need to read the documentation!

> **it.sauronsoftware.jave.InputFormatException**
>
> The source file can't be
>   decoded. It occurs when the source file container, the video stream
>   format or the audio stream format are not supported by the decoder.
>   You can check for supported containers and plugged decoders calling
>   the encoder methods

As quoted from [here](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/manual.php).

This error results form not having any decoder installed, in this case.

JAVE uses ffmpeg, and includes binaries of it for Windows and Linux.  With OSX, you need to install ffmpeg, and point JAVE to it.

[Using an alternative ffmpeg executable](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/manual.php#7)

Comment: On windows with the same video it's works.

If I change pathVideo, with a path non-existent, I have the same error. So for my mind I think it's an permission problem.

Comment: JAVE ships with an included ffmpeg binary for Windows, but not for OSX.  To use it in OSX, you need to provide an ffmpeg binary for the platform.

Comment: Read the "Using an alternative ffmpeg executable" link I have provided.  JAVE violates the Java write once run anywhere philosophy by calling system native code, which must be provided for each platform separately.